# Android app - Print out all the detected objects

Tags: java, android, tensorflow-lite

I have this code where I am detecting objects in an image.

```
try {

                        Android model = Android.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

                        // Creates inputs for reference.
                        TensorImage image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(img);

                        // Runs model inference and gets result.
                        Android.Outputs outputs = model.process(image);
                        Android.DetectionResult detectionResult = outputs.getDetectionResultList().get(0);

                        // Gets result from DetectionResult.
                        float score = detectionResult.getScoreAsFloat();
                        RectF location = detectionResult.getLocationAsRectF();
                        String category = detectionResult.getCategoryAsString();
                        //Create a new canvas to draw on
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img);
                        //draw on the canvas with the given location from the model
                        drawBoundingBox(canvas, location);
                        // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                        model.close();
                        // here we will print out the results of the object to text views based on the image that is inputted by the user
                        // we print out object type, accuracy score and location of object on the image

                        objecttv.setText(category);
                        scoretv.setText(Float.toString(score));
                        textBox.setText(newText);
                        imageBox.setImageBitmap(img);

                    }
```

How can I modify this to print out all of the objects it detects ?
Currently it only prints out one.

Comment: Can't you loop over ```outputs.getDetectionResultList()``` and print ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I done to get the second,third etc. object that is detected in case anybody

```
Android.DetectionResult detectionResult2 = outputs.getDetectionResultList().get(1);
float score2 = detectionResult2.getScoreAsFloat();
RectF location2 = detectionResult2.getLocationAsRectF();
String category2 = detectionResult2.getCategoryAsString();
```